# Django - Get Default value from another Model Field

Tags: python, django

I came across this strange problem in django where
I have 3 models `Books, Language, Book_language` where i map book to its language.

from django.db import models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.IntegerField()

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book_language(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    other_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=Book._meta.get_field('title').get_default()) # not working
```

So far i am creating a book and with title and later assigning with language so the title is same for all languages, later i understand that the title may not be the same in all languages, so i want `other_title` to be default to `title` if not mention (`but not working`), and **appear in django admin** when i map with language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you simple override `save` method?

```
class Book_language(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    other_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.other_title:
              self.other_title = self.book.title
        super(Book_language, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

for [updating-multiple-objects-at-once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.11/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) previous empty data you can use [expressions F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

empty_f = Q(other_title__isnull=True) | Q(other_title__exact='')
for bl in Book_language.objects.filter(empty_f):
    bl.other_title = bl.book.title
    bl.save()
```

Comment: thanks, 1) `ther_title` instead of `other_title` in `self.ther_title = self.book.title` intended or typo, 2) whats wrong with `Book._meta.get_field('title').get_default()` 3) previously i have data, how to migrate so that `other_title` will not be empty for previous records.

Comment: 1. yes it was a typo, 2. i don't know why it should work, for 3 i updated the answer

Comment: Hi brown when i tried to update the data with shell i am getting `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query
`